# Origine di "puntata" per gli episodi di una serie televisiva o radiofonica

Tags: etymology

Sapresti dirmi come e perché gli episodi di una serie televisiva o radiofonica, o le parti di un'opera letteraria pubblicata a più riprese vengono chiamati "puntate"? Qual è l'origine di questo uso della parola "puntata"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secondo [Garzanti](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=puntata%202) l'origine deriva da *punto* usato per bloccare  una quantità  di fogli.

Puntata:

> - ciascuna delle parti di una trasmissione televisiva o radiofonica, mandata in onda in più riprese successive: l’ultima puntata di un teleromanzo
> - ciascuna delle parti di un’opera pubblicate separatamente, in fascicoli o sui numeri di un periodico.

**Etimologia** ← deriv. di *[punto](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=punto%201)*  con riferimento alla quantità di fogli che si può fermare con un punto.

[Puntata](http://www.etimo.it/?term=puntata):  il Dizionario etimologico online parla di '*porzione di un'opera* o *dispensa* ma non suggerisce l'origine.

Comment: Cosa significa "bloccare o fermare dei fogli con un punto"?

Comment: Significa rilegarli sommariamente con una [cucitrice](https://www.google.it/search?q=cucitrice&newwindow=1&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1279&bih=702&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=SNwRVJHsOsXhPPLygcgC&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&dpr=2#newwindow=1&safe=off&tbm=isch&q=cucitrice) (o spillatrice) o, un tempo, con un tratto di filo.

Comment: Dunque, se ho capito bene, il "punto" sarebbe il tratto di filo che rilegava i fogli. È così?

Comment: Direi proprio di sì.

Comment: Charo - Sorry, I was not at the computer..just seen your comment. DaG comment is just fine. Thanks @DaG.